# hide linearLayout on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing this android app which retrieves web pages in webview and I have this banner at the top of the screen. It's not noticeable in portrait layout but in landscape, it takes up almost the top half of the screen.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#EAC117"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@raw/firstintentlogo"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:contentDescription="@string/headLogoName"/>



 </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know how to say in the java file "When the phone is in landscape mode, hide this linearLayout."

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

in your activity override onConfigurationChanged

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        //TODO
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you handle the changes yourself, you can add it to `onConfigurationChanged()` to set that `Layout`'s `visibility` to `gone`.

If you are letting the OS handle the config changes then you can create to separate `layouts` depending on orientation. You put the `layout` for portrait in the `layout` folder and you create another folder called `layout-land` so the OS knows to use the `layout` in that folder when the device is in landscape `orientation`.

[Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

[Handling config changes maunally](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) not recommended by the docs in most cases

[Allowing system to handle config changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        //check config
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //set visibility of linearLayout as Gone
    Toast.makeText(this, "mode landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
```

Hope this works